# When should Java Servlet 3.0 Filter asyncSupported be false?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

By default a Servlet Filter asyncSupported boolean is false, but it appears to cause no harm to simply set it to true, at least for a simple filter that sets the request and response character encoding.  However, if you happen to NOT change the default you can run into issues as async servlets then won't work.  Is there a scenario where enabling async support would be harmful.  Why isn't the default true / why is there even an option?  Is the filter expected to call HttpServletRequest.startAsync() if asyncSupported = true?  Can a filter handle both async and sync modes of operation?  In a simple character encoding filter is the response character encoding being set correctly when in async mode:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "CharacterEncodingFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST}, asyncSupported = true)
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```